# Properties of Derivative function on $\mathbb R[x]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $\mathbb R[x]$ denote the vector space of all real polynomials. Let $D : \mathbb R[x] \rightarrow \mathbb R[x]$denote the map $Df = \frac{df}{dx}$, for all $f$. Is there $E :\mathbb R[x] \rightarrow \mathbb R[x]$ such that $E(D(f)) = f , \forall f$?

I agree with Olivier Oola's comment that $E$ appears to act as an antiderivative.  Here's what I've tried:

First, let a function $C:\mathbb R[x]→\mathbb R[x]$ such that $C(a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n)=a_0$.  Then, define $E(a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n)=\int(a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n)+C(a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n)$.  But, I realize that this not right

Comment: If $E$ exists, it seems to act as an antiderivative...

Comment: Firstly I  have define a function $C : \mathbb R[x] \rightarrow \mathbb R[x]$ such that $C(a_0 + a_1x +....+a_nx^n) = a_0$, then define $E(a_0 + a_1x +....+a_nx^n) = \int(a_0 + a_1x +....+a_nx^n) +C(a_0 + a_1x +....+a_nx^n) $, but I realize that this not right

Comment: @ Oliver Olova : You are right, I think also

Comment: @user120386 It is $E(a_0 + a_1x +....+a_nx^n) = \int(a_0 + a_1x +....+a_nx^n) +C$ instead. No?

Answer (score 7):

Such a map cannot exist because the derivative has nontrivial kernel. The kernel consists of the constant polynomials. If $E(D(c))=c$ for some constant and $d$ is a different constant, then $E(D(d))=c\neq d$.

Comment: What about $D(E(f)) = f , \forall f$?

Comment: @srijan that is possible. We could integrate the polynomial and choose any fixed number as our additive constant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Consider the polynomials $p,p'\in\mathbb{R}$, where $p = 5$ and $p'=1$.  Then, let $\alpha = D(p) = D(p')$.  What is $E(\alpha)$?  Can $E$ be a map?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you know that a function has a left inverse iff it is injective, you only need to check if $D$ is injective, which can be fairly easily disproven.

Consider the polynomials $f_1, f_2$ with $f_1 = k, f_2 = k', k \neq k'$, then $D(f_1) = 0 = D(f_2), f_1 \neq f_2$, so $D$ is not injective, therefore there does not exist a left inverse.